# JavaFX Olympic Rings overlap in the correct order

Tags: java, javafx

this is my first time posting here. I'm currently doing an assignment where I need to create the olympic rings in JavaFX and make them intersect in the correct places.

This is what it's supposed to look like:

[image: olympic rings]
<sub>(source: [ashaw8 at ksuweb.kennesaw.edu](http://ksuweb.kennesaw.edu/~ashaw8/cs1302-07-Fall16/assignments/images/OlympicRings.png))</sub>

Currently, the rings intersect but they dominate in the order that I created the objects. Blue gets covered by yellow when they intersect, yellow gets covered by black when they intersect, etc. As you can see in the picture of the olympic rings, the first time yellow and blue intersect, yellow covers blue, but blue covers yellow the second time. Each of the rings gets covered by the other ring one time they intersect, but covers it the other time.

If anyone could point me in the right direction as to how to make them intersect properly, that would be fantastic.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
package com.company;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OlympicRings extends Application{

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        //creates a new object, which will be the first circle
        Circle circle1 = new Circle();
        circle1.setCenterX(100); //sets the x coordinate for the center of the circle
        circle1.setCenterY(100); //sets the y coordinate for the center of the circle
        circle1.setRadius(50); //sets the radius of the circle to 50, makes the diameter 100
        circle1.setStroke(Color.BLUE); //sets the color of the circle
        circle1.setStrokeWidth(10); //sets the thickness of the lines
        circle1.setFill(null); //sets the color of the inside of the circle, set to null to enable overlap

        Circle circle2 = new Circle(); //creates additional circles
        circle2.setCenterX(160);
        circle2.setCenterY(150);
        circle2.setRadius(50);
        circle2.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
        circle2.setStrokeWidth(10);
        circle2.setFill(null);

        Circle circle3 = new Circle();
        circle3.setCenterX(220);
        circle3.setCenterY(100);
        circle3.setRadius(50);
        circle3.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        circle3.setStrokeWidth(10);
        circle3.setFill(null);

        Circle circle4 = new Circle();
        circle4.setCenterX(280);
        circle4.setCenterY(150);
        circle4.setRadius(50);
        circle4.setStroke(Color.GREEN);
        circle4.setStrokeWidth(10);
        circle4.setFill(null);

        Circle circle5 = new Circle();
        circle5.setCenterX(340);
        circle5.setCenterY(100);
        circle5.setRadius(50);
        circle5.setStroke(Color.RED);
        circle5.setStrokeWidth(10);
        circle5.setFill(null);

        //creating the pane that will display the circle
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.getChildren().add(circle1); //each of these adds the various circles to the display of the pane
        pane.getChildren().add(circle2);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle3);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle4);
        pane.getChildren().add(circle5);

        Scene scene1 = new Scene(pane, 440, 250); //creates the parameters of the pane
        primaryStage.setTitle("Olympic Rings"); //names the pane
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1); //picks what will go in the pane
        primaryStage.show(); //shows the scene i've created
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible using Circles alone. Maybe by using some [Arcs](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html), rather than entire circles, you'll be able to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

This is hard to achieve with `Circle`s. This would heavy use of the `clip` property and the resulting code wouldn't be easily readable.

Instead [`Arc`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html) can be used to draw parts of the rings. Just add the covered part of the ring to the parent before adding the covering part.

Example for the first 2 rings:

```
private static Arc createArc(double radius,
                             double centerX, double centerY,
                             double fromAngle, double toAngle,
                             Paint stroke,
                             double strokeWidth) {
    Arc arc = new Arc(centerX, centerY, radius, radius, fromAngle, toAngle - fromAngle);
    arc.setFill(null);
    arc.setStroke(stroke);
    arc.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

    return arc;
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Pane pane = new Pane(
            createArc(50, 60, 60, 90, 315, Color.BLUE, 10), // part of the blue ring containing part covered by yellow
            createArc(50, 110, 110, 0, 360, Color.YELLOW, 10),
            createArc(50, 60, 60, -45, 90, Color.BLUE, 10) // part covering the yellow ring
    );

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure out the rest of the arcs, that really worked. Would you mind helping me understand exactly how the top constructor is working? I get that we create a constructor that returns Arc and then we continually call that constructor in the Start class in order to utilize it. I'm confused what the line  directly below the constructor does, the one that starts with Arc arc = new Arc. why are we listing radius twice and why do we have the line toAngle - fromAngle but not Paint stroke? Sorry if that's hard to read, i'm trying to wrap my head around this.

Comment: @TomBombadil You can find the description in the javadoc here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Arc.html#Arc-double-double-double-double-double-double- `Arc` allows you to draw oval shapes and for the special case of circles we have `radiusX == radiusY`. BTW `createArc` is not a constructor, it's a method. Constructors don't have a return type and can only be used to create instances of the containing class.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the question, I had lots of fun coming up with the following solution, see the Javadocs for the algorithm:

```
package olympicrings;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;

/**
 * This helper class knows how to paint the next olympic ring into a {@code Pane}.
 * It is not limited to 5 olympic rings, it can draw as many (or few) as desired.
 * The algorithm it follows is:
 * <ol>
 *   <li>Each ring consists of 2 arcs (half-circles) of the same color, of course.
 *       Imagine the line connecting the center of the previous ring to the center
 *       of the current: we place one arc on the LEFT of this line and one arc on
 *       the RIGHT. Let's call them arcs L and R. These need to be added to the
 *       children {@code Node}s of the {@code Pane} at the correct order.</li>
 *   <li>The placement of arc L depends on whether the current ring is at the top
 *       row or at the bottom:
 *       <ul>
 *           <li>TOP: It goes below arc L of the previous ring</li>
 *           <li>BOTTOM: It goes below arc R of the previous ring</li>
 *       </ul>
 *   </li>
 *   <li>Arc R is always placed last in the list of the children of the {@code Pane}.</li>
 *   <li>Advance the position of the next ring, taking into account the desired
 *       ring radius and stroke width.</li>
 * </ol>
 * <p>
 * Usage:
 * <pre><code>
 * OlympicRingsPaintingContext ctx = new OlympicRingsPaintingContext(thePane, 50, 10);
 * ctx.paintNextRing(Color.BLUE);
 * ...
 * </code></pre>
 */
public class OlympicRingsPaintingContext {

    /**
     * A handy constant containing the standard olympic colors. Could be used as follows
     * to paint the standard olympic rings:
     * <pre><code>
     * OlympicRingsPaintingContext ctx = new OlympicRingsPaintingContext(thePane, 50, 10);
     * OlympicRingsPaintingContext.STANDARD_OLYMPIC_COLORS.forEach(ctx::paintNextRing);
     * </code></pre>
     */
    public static final List<Color> STANDARD_OLYMPIC_COLORS = Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(Color.BLUE, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK, Color.GREEN, Color.RED));

    private static final double[] TOP_START_ANGLES = new double[] {45, 225};
    private static final double[] BOTTOM_START_ANGLES = new double[] {315, 135};

    private Pane pane;
    private double radius;
    private double strokeWidth;
    private double curx;
    private double cury;
    private double topy;
    private double bottomy;
    private double startAngleL;
    private double startAngleR;
    private int prevIndexL;
    private int prevIndexR;

    public OlympicRingsPaintingContext(Pane pane, double radius, double strokeWidth) {
        this.pane = pane;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        topy = 2*radius;
        bottomy = 3*radius;
        curx = 2*radius;
        cury = topy;
        startAngleL = TOP_START_ANGLES[0];
        startAngleR = TOP_START_ANGLES[1];
        prevIndexL = 0;
        prevIndexR = 0;
    }

    public void paintNextRing(Color color) {
        addArcL(color);
        addArcR(color);
        advance();
    }

    private void addArcL(Color color) {
        Arc arcL = makeArc(startAngleL, color);
        if( cury == topy ) {
            pane.getChildren().add(prevIndexL, arcL);
        }
        else {
            pane.getChildren().add(prevIndexR, arcL);
            prevIndexL = prevIndexR;
        }
    }

    private void addArcR(Color color) {
        Arc arcR = makeArc(startAngleR, color);
        pane.getChildren().add(arcR);
        prevIndexR = pane.getChildren().size() - 1;
    }

    private Arc makeArc(double startAngle, Color color) {
        Arc arc = new Arc(curx, cury, radius, radius, startAngle, 180);
        arc.setFill(null);
        arc.setStroke(color);
        arc.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
        return arc;
    }

    private void advance() {
        curx += radius + strokeWidth;
        if( cury == topy ) {
            cury = bottomy;
            startAngleL = BOTTOM_START_ANGLES[0];
            startAngleR = BOTTOM_START_ANGLES[1];
        }
        else {
            cury = topy;
            startAngleL = TOP_START_ANGLES[0];
            startAngleR = TOP_START_ANGLES[1];
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
package olympicrings;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class OlympicRingsApplication extends Application {

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        OlympicRingsPaintingContext ctx = new OlympicRingsPaintingContext(pane, 50, 10);
        OlympicRingsPaintingContext.STANDARD_OLYMPIC_COLORS.forEach(ctx::paintNextRing);
// nobody stops you here though...
//      ctx.paintNextRing(javafx.scene.paint.Color.AQUA);

        Scene scene1 = new Scene(pane, 440, 250); // creates the parameters of the pane
        primaryStage.setTitle("Olympic Rings"); // names the pane
        primaryStage.setScene(scene1); // picks what will go in the pane
        primaryStage.show(); // shows the scene i've created
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```